# Light-head after squats

Tags: squats

I have been trying to get into regular exercising and started with a few reps of no-weight squats at home. I have high BMI of around 30 (though my bone-density is also high) for a reference.

I did 15 reps of squats for a 4 days took a day off then did 20 the next day and ever time (at least for the last day when I did 20 reps) I felt a bit light-headed.

Should I continue exercising or see a doctor?

Related [post](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/light-headedness-after-squats).

Some background - I have gained around 10-15 kgs of weight in the past couple of years and there is practically no physical exertion I undergo. Furthermore, I recovered from corona virus in August but had resting heart rate of 95+ for more than a month which came down to 80s after a month (this is quite common in recovered patients as an google query will show). Furthermore, I might have been infected again and recovered around 10 days back although there were absolute zero signs this time around. As a last point, I tried to donate blood plasma (this was my first time donating blood) and about a syringe (~ 10-20 ml) of blood sample was taken from me after which I felt extreme light-headedness to the point of almost passing out and ultimately decided to not donate the plasma.

As I write this looks more and more like something that would belong on health.SE (if it exists). Please let me know if this is appropriate and if it is not then I will delete it. At this point I am just looking for any experienced opinions.

Comment: What about the related post didn't answer your question?

Comment: @C.Lange No, it did not, specially since 15-20 reps of un-weighted squats should be nothing. The background that I provided also seems relevant to me.